# dictionary key type confusion isinstance python

Tags: python, dictionary

I can't understand following execution. I expected different results.

```
>>> f = {'ms':'ma'}
>>> isinstance(f['ms'], type(str))
False

>>> isinstance(f['ms'], type(dict))
False

>>> type(f['ms'])
<class 'str'>
```

Comment: `type(str)` returns `type`, so you are checking if `f['ms']` is an instance of `type`, not an instance of `str`. If you want to check if something is a string, use `isinstance(f['ms'], str)`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`type(str)` and `type(dict)` each return `type`, so you are checking if your objects are **instances of `type`**, which they are not.

If you want to check if something is a string, use

```
isinstance(f['ms'], str)
```

not

```
isinstance(f['ms'], type(str))
```

And if you want to test if something is a `dict`, you can use

```
isinstance(f['ms'], dict)
```

not

```
isinstance(f['ms'], type(dict))
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you just want this:

```
>>> f = {'ms':'ma'}
>>> isinstance(f['ms'], str)
True
```

You don't need `type(str)`